# Confused about StripTags filter

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-filter-strip-tags

I'm a little confused about the StripTags filter as used in Zend. I think it's meant to strip tags that could result in XSS. So shouldn't that mean it should be used when outputting data in the views? I've seen it being used with form inputs

```
->addFilter('StripTags')
```

Should it be used with both input in the forms and output in the views, or does it work by filtering the data before it even enters the database (in which case that wouldn't be a good idea).

Comment: Maybe you should be asking "What the hell is xss?"

Comment: @Rook, I know what XSS is as is clear from my question.

Comment: then you should be able  to answer your own question.

Comment: @Rook, Thanks for being so helpful, but considering that zend-framework is no where in your top 60 tags (those with at least 6 questions) and who knows how many zend-framework questions you tried to answer before (less than 5 for sure, could be 1, this could be your first), you really shouldn't be trying that hard to be so helpful. This is a zend implementation question.

Comment: So you mean to tell me  that zend's StripTags is even worse than striptags()?  You should be using `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` because you don't always need a `<script>` to get xss.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so much a direct answer to your question and more an alternative approach.

In the blog post ["HTML Sanitisation: The Devil's In The Details (And The Vulnerabilities)"](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2010/08/html-sanitisation-the-devils-in-the-details-and-the-vulnerabilities/), Padraic Brady discusses HTML sanitisation and various components for doing it. He expresses significant concerns about the use of the StripTags filter for that purpose.

[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) seems to be a better choice.

Comment: Nice find. Padraic always comes up with good stuff. I do agree that HTMLPurifier is the best outside of zend so I hope the proposal he's talking about makes it through to zend 2, coz I've got a feeling stripTags has a flawed implementation underneath.. though that question itself is still open for answering.

Comment: Right, it's still a valid question, one that I kind of sidestepped. Thanks for not taking me to task on it. And for what I assume are your upvotes. ;-)

Comment: Helpful answers deserve the upvote man, it's a little thank you for bothering to help.

Answer (score 0):

StripTags is used with output in the views.
Note, that displaying text in editable field(such as textarea) is actually still an "output in the view".
Data should not be preprocessed/transformed before entering the database.

Answer (score 0):

The strip tag filter will not occur unless you explicitly call it through

```
$stripedValue = $form->getValue('fieldName');
```

Answer (score 0):

according to ZF2 unofficial documentation:

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.filter.set.html#striptags

Zend\Filter\StripTags is potentially unsecure

Be warned that Zend\Filter\StripTags should only be used to strip all available tags.

Using Zend\Filter\StripTags to make your site secure by stripping some unwanted tags will lead to unsecure and dangerous code.

Zend\Filter\StripTags must not be used to prevent XSS attacks. This filter is no replacement for using Tidy or HtmlPurifier.

So use it on your own risk...